# How to write mulliple validators function in one form (Reactive Forms) in angular?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular-forms

I am using Reactive forms

My form is like this

```
this.fb.group({
            percentAllocation: [''],
            constantPercent: [''],
            allocStartDate: [''],
            allocEndDate: [''],
                   },  { validator: this.percentageValidator('percentAllocation', 'constantPercent'))
```

I need to two types of validation

1) `allocStartDate < allocEndDate`

2)`percentAllocation > constantPercent`

Thease two above validations are dependeing two form controles each other. I try to write validation like this

```
 percentageValidator(rowPercentage, constantPercent) {
    return (group: FormGroup): { [key: string]: any } => {
        let r = group.controls[rowPercentage];
        let c = group.controls[constantPercent]
        if (r.value > c.value) {
            return {
                percentage: true
            };
        }
        return {};
    }
}

dateLessThan(from: string, to: string) {

    console.log(from, to)
    return (group: FormGroup): { [key: string]: any } => {
        let f = group.controls[from];
        let t = group.controls[to];
        if (f.value > t.value) {
            return {
                dates: true
            };
        }
        return {};
    }
}
```

Please help me to put multiple for validation , and error message should be through form ts only

Comment: Have a look at answer provided by me:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why go for the complicated solution when there exists an easier and better one.

I prefer the below approach To Compare two controls inside Custom Validator

Component

```
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
  public myForm: FormGroup;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      percentAllocation: new FormControl('21'),
      constantPercent: new FormControl('26', this.percentageValidator),
      allocStartDate: new FormControl('', this.dateLessThan),
      allocEndDate: new FormControl(''),
    })
    this.myForm.statusChanges.subscribe(val => console.log(val))
  }

  percentageValidator(control: FormControl): { [key: string]: boolean } {
    if (control.parent) {
      let c = Number(control.parent.value['percentAllocation']);
      let r = Number(control.value);
      if (r > c) {
        return {
          'percentage': true
        };
      }
      else return null;
    }
  }

  dateLessThan(control: FormControl): { [key: string]: boolean } {
    if (control.parent) {
      let f = control.parent.value['allocEndDate']
      let t = control.value
      if (new Date(f) < new Date(t)) {
        return {
          'dates': true
        };
      }
      else
        return null;
 }
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="peralloc">percentAllocation</label>
  <input type="text" 
   class="form-control" formControlName="percentAllocation">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="conper">constantPercent</label>
  <input type="text"  class="form-control" 
  formControlName="constantPercent">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="allocstart">allocStartDate</label>
  <input type="date"  class="form-control" 
  formControlName="allocStartDate">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="allocEnd">allocEndDate</label>
 <input  class="form-control" type="date" 
 formControlName="allocEndDate">
    </div>
 <div *ngIf="myForm.get('constantPercent').errors && myForm?.get('constantPercent')?.errors?.percentage">
     percentAllocation should be greater than constantPercent
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="myForm.get('allocStartDate').errors && myForm?.get('allocStartDate')?.errors?.date ">
     end Date should be greater than start Date
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Added Bit of Bootstrap ;)

**[`Live Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactiveformvali)**

Comment: I want to write error message should from ts not directly from html

Comment: @SoumyaGangamwar Sorry, I did not understand? Can you elaborate more?

Comment: The error message "  end Date should be greater than start Date
" should come from component.

Comment: @SoumyaGangamwar oKay you can use Interpolation for that. what about validation `*ngIf="myForm.get('constantPercent').errors && myForm?.get('constantPercent')?.errors?.percentage"` do you wanna do it in component??.Lemme know so that i can update my answer

Comment: This validator is not reusable at all. Following the official documentation the better approach is provided in the question. Comparing 2 FormControl fields on FormGroup level. 
Accessing another FormControl through FormGroup (parent) is not desired

Comment: @AlexanderGolovinov feel free to update the answer and add relevant links , I wrote this long time ago and honestly haven't had the time to update it